# Android Spinner value and text

Tags: android, spinner

Hello I have question about android spinner

I have spinner which is populated by array.The array is Country name and Country phone code on every row

**Part of the array**

```
<item>355  Albania</item>
<item>213  Algeria</item>
<item>376  Andorra</item>
<item>244  Angola</item>
<item>1264  Anguilla</item>
<item>1268  Antigua and Barbuda</item>
<item>54  Argentina</item>
```

This is my java code for populating the spinner

```
final Spinner spnCountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.countries);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adpCountry = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.countries, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adpCountry
    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spnCountry.setAdapter(adpCountry);
```

I want to show only country code on the box and when the spinner is opened to show country name and code on every row.

Can someone help me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading the Spinner;

```
String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);

ArrayAdapter<String> adpCountry = new ArrayAdapter<String>();
for(String country : countries)
{
    String parts = country.split(" ");
    String code = parts[0];

    adpCountry.addItem(code);
}

adpCountry.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spnCountry.setAdapter(adpCountry);
```

Selecting an item;

```
spnCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int index, long arg3)
    {
        String country = "";
        String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);

        String selected = countries[index];
        String[] parts = selected.split(" ");
        for(String part : parts)
        {
            country += part;
        }

        TextView txtName = findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        txtName.setText(country);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){ /* Unused */ }
});
```

*(out of heart)*

Comment: Hello i have tried your code but there is an                    error 12-16 15:40:27.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(245): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
12-16 15:40:27.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(245):     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:411)
12-16 15:40:27.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(245):     at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:432)
12-16 15:40:27.961: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(245):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(ArrayAdapter.java:178)
The method addItem(String) is undefined for the type ArrayAdapter<String> tried with addItem and add

Comment: Also what i want to do is: when spinner is shown i want to be visible only country code and when i click on the spinner and the list is opened i want to see country code and country name